# Query to Select record between next 1 hour from given date time,also data must be less than 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a scheduler which runs every hour.I need to fetch data older than 7 days and data must be between scheduler passed time part to scheduler passed time part + 59 min (To fetch data between between current scheduler hour to next scheduler running hour )

@schedulartime=2020-03-25 23:00

```
 id       createddate
-------    --------
1           2020-03-17 23:05
2           2020-03-24 23:05
3           2020-03-15 23:59
4           2020-03-15 22:25
```

The query should return id's 1,3

So far i tried with time

```
select *
from tablename
where CreatedDate <= dateadd(day,-7,@schedulartime) and
      CONVERT(TIME, CreatedDate) >= CONVERT(TIME, @schedulartime) and
      CONVERT(TIME, CreatedDate) < convert(time,dateadd(hour,1,@schedulartime))
```

which fails if i pass schedulartime greater than 23:00

ie : if schedulertime =23:05,with my query CONVERT(TIME, CreatedDate) < convert(time,dateadd(hour,1,@schedulartime)  => 23:05 < 00:04 fails

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @schedulartime DATETIME = '2020-03-25 23:09'
select * 
from [dbo].[Table_1]
where cdate <= dateadd(n, 59, dateadd(n,-10080,@schedulartime)) and
      cdate < dateadd(n,59,@schedulartime)
```

Comment: suppose scheduler time ='2020-03-25 23:05' ,adding 59 minutes will make time part 00:04 ,Now last condition CONVERT(TIME, cdate) <=  DATEADD(mi, 59,   convert(time,@schedulartime))  which is 23:05<=00:04 will not be true.So any data after 23:05 won't list

Comment: Please update you question and provide several cases/examples of valid and invalid data and result in table format in order to make the query testable

Comment: The answer was based on this part of your question : convert(time,@schedulartime+1hour)

Comment: sorry, My issue is above scenario ,If i write logic based on time ,the last hour (23:00+) will cause issue if scheduler time is greater than 23:00

Comment: Well, based on case understanding, answer has been edited.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please explain what you done.What is n and -10080 string refers ?

Comment: Happy to hear that, I noticed the days argument does not satisfy the requirement so I used the minutes (1 week = 10080 minutes ). you even can simplify the query by replacing dateadd(n, 59, dateadd(n,-10080,@schedulartime))  with  dateadd(n,-10021,@schedulartime) ( i.e: -10080 + 59)